# How to make a xml tag a row in excel?

Tags: xml, excel

I am new to xml files so I need some help here please. I need to import a xml file into excel but I cannot get the formatting right.  What is in the "P" tag I need to be in one row, with the attribute value (the n value) being the column header. What is in the "D" tag occurs many times in the file I am working with, the id of "D" goes up to 31. All of these tags are in a "B" tag. There is sensitive information in these so I had to replace the text with stuff, sorry. I hope this all makes sense, any information or pointing in the right direction is appreciated. Thank you.

```
<D id="1">
    <V n="stuff1">stuff1</V>
    <V n="stuff2">stuff2</V>
    <V n="stuff3">stuff3</V>

    <P id="stuff11">
        <V n="stuff111">stuff111</V>
        <V n="stuff112">stuff112</V>
        <V n="stuff113">stuff113</V>
        <V n="stuff114">stuff114</V>
        <V n="stuff115">stuff115</V>
        <V n="stuff116">stuff116</V>
    </P>
</D>

<D id="2">
    <V n="stuff1">stuff1</V>
    <V n="stuff2">stuff2</V>
    <V n="stuff3">stuff3</V>

    <P id="stuff21">
        <V n="stuff111">stuff211</V>
        <V n="stuff112">stuff212</V>
        <V n="stuff113">stuff213</V>
        <V n="stuff114">stuff214</V>
        <V n="stuff115">stuff215</V>
        <V n="stuff116">stuff216</V>
    </P>
</D>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have have found previously that Excel imports the element values but not attributes within those elements. For example "stuff211" imports stuff211 but not stuff111. I assume that this is just a limitation in how the functionality works in Excel. Does the import have to be in Excel or can you use a programming language such as Python? I have written a procedure before to extract specific element and attribute values from an xml file, which I would be happy to dig out and share tomorrow if required?

**UPDATE**

Here is a python script that I have written and used previously to strip data from an xml file into a csv file. Note, I have not yet set this up to get all attributes and elements as my initial purpose was to just get specific data from a file. You will need to edit the search_items global list to the items that you want to search for.

You can call the script from the command line with a single argument for the path of the xml file or you can use without an arg and you will be prompted to select a directory. Please let me know if you have any questions:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Change Ideas
# ------------
# Add option to get all xml elements / attributes
# Add support for json?

import sys, os, Tkinter, tkFileDialog as fd, traceback

# stop tinker shell from opening as only needed for file dialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# globals
debug_on = False
#get_all_elements = False
#get_all_attributes = False

# search items to be defined each time you run to identify values to search for.
# each item should have a search text, a type and optionally a heading e.g.
# search_items = ['exact_serach_text', 'item_type', 'column_heading(optional)']
# note: search items are case sensitive.
#
##############################   E X A M P L E   ##############################
search_items = [
    ['policyno=',                       'xml_attribute',    'Policy No'    ],
    ['transid=',                        'xml_attribute',    'Trans ID'     ],
    ['policyPremium=',                  'xml_attribute',    'Pol Prem'     ],
    ['outstandingBalance=',             'xml_attribute',    'Balance'      ],
    ['APRCharge=',                      'xml_attribute',    'APR Chrg'     ],
    ['PayByAnnualDD=',                  'xml_attribute',    'Annual DD'    ],
    ['PayByDD=',                        'xml_attribute',    'Pay by DD'    ],
    ['mtaDebitAmount=',                 'xml_attribute',    'MTA Amt'      ],
    ['paymentMethod=',                  'xml_attribute',    'Pmt Meth'     ],
    ['ddFirstPaymentAmount=',           'xml_attribute',    '1st Amt'      ],
    ['ddRemainingPaymentsAmount=',      'xml_attribute',    'Other Amt'    ],
    ['ddNumberOfPaymentsRemaining=',    'xml_attribute',    'Instl Rem'    ],
    ]
item_types = ['xml_attribute', 'xml_element']

def get_heads():
    heads = []
    for i in search_items:
        try:
            # raise error if i[2] does not exist or is empty
            assert len(i[2]) > 0, "No value in heading, use search text."
        except:
            heads.append(i[0]) # use search item as not heading is given
        else:
            heads.append(i[2])
    return heads

def write_csv_file(path, heads, data):
    """
    Writes data to file, use None for heads param if no headers required.
    """
    with open(path, 'wb') as fileout:
        writer = csv.writer(fileout)
        if heads:
            writer.writerow(heads)
        for row in data:
            try:
                writer.writerow(row)
            except:
                print '...row failed in write to file:', row
                exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
                lines = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
                for line in lines:
                    print '!!', line
    print 'Data written to:', path, '\n'

def find_val_in_line(item, item_type, line):
    if item_type.lower() == 'xml_element':
        print 'Testing still in progress for xml elements, please check output carefully'
        b1, b2 = ">", "<"
        tmp = line.find(item) # find the starting point of the element value
        x = line.find(b1, tmp+1) + len(boundary) # find next boundary after item
        y = line.find(b2, x) # find subsequent boundary to mark end of element value
        return line[x:y]
    elif item_type.lower() == 'xml_attribute':
        b = '"'
        tmp = line.find(item) # find the starting point of the attribute
        x = line.find(b, tmp+1) + len(b) # find next boundary after item
        y = line.find(b, x) # find subsequent boundary to mark end of attribute
        return line[x:y] # return value between start and end boundaries
    else:
        print 'This program does not currently support type:', item_type
        print 'Returning null'
        return None

def find_vals_in_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        buf = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)
        data, row = [], []
        found_in_row, pos = 0, 0
        l = len(search_items)
        if debug_on: print '\nsearch_items set to:\n' + str(search_items) + '\n'

        # loop through the lines in the file...
        for line in buf:
            if debug_on: print '\n..line set to:\n  ' + line

            # loop through search items on each line...
            for i in search_items:
                if debug_on: print '...item set to:\n  ' + i[0]

                # if the search item is found in the line...
                if i[0] in line:

                    val = find_val_in_line(i[0], i[1], line)

                    # only count as another item found if not already in that row
                    try:
                        # do not increment cnt if this works as item already exists
                        row[pos] = val
                        if debug_on: print '.....repeat item found:- ' + i[0] + ':' + val
                    except IndexError:
                        found_in_row += 1 # Index does not exist, count as new
                        row.append(val)
                        if debug_on: print '....item found, row set to:\n    ' + str(row)

                    # if we have a full row then add row to data and start row again...
                    if found_in_row == l:
                        if debug_on: print '......row complete, appending to data\n'
                        data.append(row)
                        row, found_in_row = [], 0
                pos += 1 # start at 0 and increment 1 at end of each search item
            pos = 0
        f.close()
    return data

def main():
    path, matches = None, []
    os.chdir(os.getenv('userprofile'))

    # check cmd line args provided...
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        path = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        while not path:
            try:
                print 'Please select a file to be parsed...'
                path = fd.askopenfilename()
            except:
                print 'Error selecting file, please try again.'

    # search for string in each file...
    try:
        matches = find_vals_in_file(path)
    except:
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        lines = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
        print "An error occurred checking file:", path
        print ''.join('!! ' + line for line in lines)

    # write output to file...
    if len(matches) == 0:
        print "No matches were found in the files reviewed."
    else:
        heads = get_heads()            
        output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'tmp_matches.csv')
        write_csv_file(output_path, heads, matches)
        print "Please rename the file if you wish to keep it as it will be overwritten..."
        print "\nOpening file..."
        os.startfile(output_path)

        if debug_on:
            print "\nWriting output to screen\n", "-"*24
            print heads
            for row in matches:
                print row

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope this works for you. I have only tested on a couple of different xml files so far, but worked okay for me.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I would love it if you could share that with me. I was trying for excel just because I thought doing it in excel should be easy. If you could share what you have with me I would be eternally grateful. I can see if it works for me, no harm in trying :)

Comment: No problem, I will post it tomorrow. Do you have Python installed already? If not you can download it from http://www.python.org/download/, let me know if you're not sure which version you need etc.

Comment: I didn't have Python installed so I just grabbed it quick, simple enough. I will have to play around with this now, never worked with Python before, I only do Java at my job. I will look for your follow up post tomorrow then.

Comment: Cool, if you want a quick tutorial to cover the basics, check out: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/

Comment: I have updated the answer with the code for the Python script, let me know if you have any questions.